# haskell: convert string with unicode characters to chunks of 64 bits

Tags: haskell, unicode

I'd like to convert a `String` to chunks of 64 bits. I'm not sure whether `ByteString` is the correct data type to use, but after some testing I realized that I can't convert a `String` to a `ByteString` and back:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
main = putStrLn $ B.unpack $ B.pack "☂♞☯"
```

Result:

```
^/
```

Shouldn't this print `☂♞☯`?

My second attempt was to split the `String` into a list of `Int`s, each `Int` representing a character:

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ map fromEnum "☂♞☯"
```

Result:

```
[9730,9822,9775]
```

Now how can I convert this list into a list of 64 bit chunks? It is important that I'm able to convert the 64 bit chunks back to a `String` afterwards, without losing any information.

Comment: In Haskell `String` represents a Unicode string. Which encoding do you want to use to convert a Unicode string into byte form?

Comment: I guess you mean serialization? Have you checked `Data.Binary`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `ByteString.Char8` documentation says](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html) (emphasis mine):

> Manipulate `ByteStrings` using `Char` operations. All Chars will be **truncated to 8 bits**. It can be expected that these functions will run at identical speeds to their Word8 equivalents in [Data.ByteString](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html).

IOW, this only works as you'd expect for pure ASCII strings. Well, the `Char8` in the module name rather suggests this already, doesn't it? So, no, it should not print `☂♞☯`.

Your second approach makes more sense. To make it reliable you should use not `Int` but `Word64`; you can convert to such a type by using `fromIntegral . fromEnum` instead of just the latter.

It's not really advisable to try building a `ByteString` directly from such words, because purely functional concatenation of array-like things doesn't work well. But the [`Binary.Builder`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.2.1/docs/Data-Binary-Builder.html) module has an efficient monoid for this purpose. A monoid can directly be mapped over a list:

```
> toLazyByteString $ foldMap (putWord64le . fromIntegral . fromEnum) "☂♞☯"
"\STX&\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL^&\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL/&\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL"
```

So, these are the actual 64-bit chunks you asked for. Basicall UTF-64, which is of course highly space-inefficient.

Depending on what you want to do, a better alternative might be to just [encode](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.2.1/docs/Data-Binary.html#v:encode) the string:

```
Prelude Data.Binary> encode "☂♞☯"
"\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\NUL\ETX\226\152\130\226\153\158\226\152\175"
```

This actually stores the string as UTF-8 (plus the *length* information stored in the first eight bytes). This can be very easily undone:

```
Prelude Data.Binary> putStrLn . decode $ encode "☂♞☯"
☂♞☯
```

Answer (score 2):

### UTF-8

Assuming UTF-8, the `utf8-string` package implements the desired encoding algorithm. The `encode` function below takes a `String` and returns an array of unsigned bytes.

```
module Main where

import Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as UTF8

main :: IO ()
main =
  print (UTF8.encode "☂♞☯")
```

Output:

```
λ> main
[226,152,130,226,153,158,226,152,175]
```

As you can see, UTF-8 represents your Unicode string as nine different bytes. You'll have to write your own code to convert them into chunks of 64 bits. There are lots of different ways of chunking them!